# The model field, which is only modifiable in the function

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In my project there is information about the devices and their verification.

There are data with dates, these dates indicate the periods of verification.

I need to create a BooleanField, which can only be changed by the custom function that the user invokes in the admin panel.

So here's how to create a BooleanField, which will be hidden in the forms of modification and addition.

**UPD:**
I found a solution, and described it in the answers. But the question remains how to hide it in the forms of adding and changing.

Comment: do you want it to hide from admin panel or from any other front-end form?

Comment: @SHIVAM JINDAL From the forms of adding and changing to the admin panel.

Comment: Your answer seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was obvious. Add this field to `readonly_fields` in `admin.py`.